# How to pass or implement the data from decodable model to ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

I don't know how to pass or implement the data from Decodable Model to ViewController. And I'm expecting status 200 or msg "success" in my view controller. So I can put it in my UIButton to show the user that the server was connected.

I tried debugPrint(response) a while ago and the API is working fine.

My Model

```
struct ServerStatus: Decodable {

    let status: Int?
    let service: String?
    let function: String?
    let msg: String?

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    case status = "status"
    case service = "service"
    case function = "function"
    case msg = "msg"
  }
}
```

My API Call using Alamofire 5.0

```
class APIManager {
    static let sharedInstance = APIManager()

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
         .authorization(APIDefinitions.api_id)
    ]

    func fetchServerStatus(parameters: Parameters, completion:@escaping (_ data: ServerStatus?, _ error: String?) -> Void){
        AF.request(APIDefinitions.getServerStatus, method: .get, headers: headers).responseDecodable(of: ServerStatus.self) { (response) in
            print(response)
            switch response.result{
                case .success(let serverStatus):
                    completion(serverStatus, nil)
                    break
                case .failure( _):
                    completion(nil, "The Internet connection appears to be offline.")
                    break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your ViewCotroller code ?

Comment: only touchUpInside IBAction func onlineModePressed(_ sender: Any) { } and IBOutlet weak var connect: UIButton!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The APIManager you've already handles the networking part. Now you just need to call this function in ViewController's `viewDidLoad`, like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let button = UIButton()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        APIManager.sharedInstance.fetchServerStatus(parameters: nil) { (response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                button.setTitle("Connection Failed", for: .normal)
            } else if let status = status {
                if response.status == 200 || response.msg == "success" {
                    button.setTitle("Connected", for: .normal)
                } else {
                    button.setTitle("Connection Failed", for: .normal)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what should I put in completion parameter my good sir?

Comment: Which completion parameter?

Comment: thanks, it works now from your solution, just made little changes according to my preferences.

Comment: @Chi If the answer worked then mark it as right and upvote when you are able to.